# Show that $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{14}(15-x)$ given $x=15-12e^{\frac{-t}{14}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A biologist is researching the growth of a certain species of hamster. She proposes that the length, $x$cm, of a hamster $t$ days after its birth is given by

$x=15-12e^{\frac{-t}{14}}$

Show that $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{14}(15-x)$

I get $-(-\frac{12}{14}e^{\frac{-t}{14}})$ using the chain rule, but I'm told that it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**: $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -12e^{-\frac{t}{14}}\left(\dfrac{-1}{14}\right)$, and $\dfrac{15-x}{14} = ...?$

Comment: Haha, wow... Practice makes perfect I guess, my bad. Thanks